# How to get the last day of previous month in Unix in simple steps

Tags: unix

I have a requirement in UNIX to get the last day of previous month in terms of date. I couldn't find this anywhere and I did some R and D and got a simple solution and I thought of sharing the same.

Comment: I think you could improve your question by adding some more info like what did you find and what is that you help with. Please go through this guide(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to put a good questions

Answer (score 0):

`date -d "-$(date +%d) days -0 month" +%Y-%m-%d` -> previous month
`date -d "-$(date +%d) days -1 month" +%Y-%m-%d` -> previous to previous month

Example output:

```
$ date +%Y-%m-%d  
2019-08-21
$ date -d "-$(date +%d) days -0 month" +%Y-%m-%d
2019-07-31
$ date -d "-$(date +%d) days -1 month" +%Y-%m-%d
2019-06-30
```